# Index for list slices

Tags: python, list, indexing, lookup, slice

Consider this main list:

```
 main_list = [['room A0', 'level0'], 
              ['room A1', ''], 
              ['room John Doe', ''],
              ['room 10', 'levelz'], 
              ['room 102', ''],
              ['Big hall', 'level1a'], 
              ['xyz', '']]
```

It is an ordered list:

```
- level0: 0,1,2
- levelz: 3,4
- level1a: 5,6
```

I would like to create a second list (or other data structure),
 which helps me *fast* lookup.

Example:

```
question: 'Give me index 4', 
answer: 'room 102', 'levelz' (hidden lookup for levelz, which is at index3)
```

The main_list list is typically reads many times, and modified only occasionally.

Right now this is my solution:

```
 par_table = ['level0', 'level1', 'level1a']
 ref_par_table = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2]
```

`ref_par_table` list is exactly the same length as the original `main_list`.

`par_table` contains only the keywords, picked from the original list.

When I modify the `main_list`, I also update the `par_table` and `ref_par_table` too.

So the original example, looks like this:

```
question: 'Give me index 4', 
answer: main_list[4], par_table[ref_par_table[4]] 
('room 102', 'levelz')
```

**Are there any more elegant way of doing this?**

**EDIT**: My question is more about the data structure, then actual parsing of the main_list.
In real life, the main list is typically between 1000-99000 elements, where each element is a list of 7 length. So parsing(searching) the `main_list` for each lookup is a **big no** in this case.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the strange data structure `main_list`?

Comment: Yes. The above example is a simplified data structure. The original one is list of lists too, and reflects a fixed width table, where the number of cols are 7, and number of rows (lines) are typically 1000-99000. It is part of a gui program each keystroke operation must be strictly under 10ms (worst case: 20ms). So I handle a pretty big table basically realtime on a moderate laptop.

Comment: You want lookups. Any particular reason why you're not using dictionaries?

Comment: msvalkon: you just replied, while I was editing my previous answer. Basically list of lists reflect a **fixed width** table.

Comment: msvalkon: maybe for _lookup_ the dictionary is the right datastructure. Care to develop your idea a bit more?

Comment: Since lists are mutable, when you update `main_list` why not actually set the floor for every room, instead of updating ref_par_table? Either way, you need to iterate over every room, right?

Comment: The lists is the exact representation to an actual file on the disk. So if I pollute with autogenerated data is not the clever idea. Especially, when the program makes a distinction between autogenerated data (lookups) and original data (ie. you only need to modify the main_list[3] (levelz) to _autoupdate_ all other elements)

Comment: When I load the file, I create the `main_list`, `par_table`, `ref_par_table`. After that I only need to modify `par_table` and `ref_par_table` when the `main_list` changes. So definietly not for each lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `main_list` for the right level number like this:

```
def getRoomTuple(list, index):
    name = list[index][0]
    level = list[index][1]
    i = 0
    while level is "":
        level = list[index-i][1]
        i += 1
    return name, level

print getRoomTuple(main_list, 2) # ('room John Doe', 'level0')
```

You only need to step over as many list items as it takes to find the last room with a specified `level`. So `getRoomTuple(0)` will return straight away; `getRoomTuple(2)` has to check indices 2, 1 and 0.

If possible, you should also use more semantic data structures.

```
class Room(object):
    name = None
    level = None
    def __init__(self, name, level):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level

main_list = [Room('A0', 'level0'), Room('A1', 'level1'), ...]
```

Comment: It is very well possible you wont get a hit until 4-500 lines before. So searching through the `main_list` for each lookup is not the way to go. However thank you very much for your snippets, I'm saving it for other usecases (for real search, and not lookup). Also it is a fixed width table, I don't think converting each line to a class is the most efficient way.